# Marketing Cloud journey record creation in service cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey with 10 records to start with, the only step is to create a record in service cloud.

only 1 out of the 10 entry records create a record in the service cloud.

How can i see which ones failed and why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the api logs in service cloud? These are "soft" errors and are likely due to missing required field, improper value for a field, duplicates, and you may gather all the info you need fro the api logs, otherwise you will need a support case to have support pull the errors